no colors in vi (vim(1)) when ssh from Windows to Linux. How to fix?
Windows Terminal 1.19.10573.0
When I ssh from Windows into a linux machine, I got colored output on the shell just fine. Directories and files are colored when using ls(1). Same with grep(1); results are marked in color. I got the same results when I use putty, so I think it's an issue on the (oldish) linux system (CentOS 7, no worries we are phasing them out.. :-)).
Just if I use vi (vim) (or nano(1) for that matter), there is no color at all. I barely see the cursor which led to some mistyping in the past.
I tried the usual suspects in .vimrc and on the : command within vi, i.e.
syntax on
set hlsearch
set ruler
set showmatch
colorscheme
etc..
Beside that the features seem (?) to work.. there is no effect on colors.
For example, hlsearch would not highlight the search results..
What can I do to at least make the cursor more prominently visible?

Are you invoking Vim on the command line as "vi" or "vim"? CentOS includes a basic version of Vim with no color support installed as /bin/vi, but an enhanced version can be installed that would be invoked as vim.

Also, what's your $TERM environmental variable set to (and how is it set)?

I invoke as "vi". "vim" is not found.

I invoke as "vi". "vim" is not found.
Within vi (vim), the version is reported as "VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.4.629 by Bram Moolenaar et al.". Does that support colors in CentOS 7?
$TERM shows as "xterm-256color"

Install vim-enhanced and invoke as 'vim".

Did my suggestion work?

Unfortunately, I cannot install anything anymore on that machine. Too old.
